# How can I have a wrap horizontal alignment of cards in vuetify 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a tiny project that I am building using vuetify 2, but the issue I am coming across is in a col with width 7, all my cards are showing up vertically, instead of a horizontal overflow.

What I am hoping to achieve is that the cards are vertical to each other by counts of five, with overflow moving to the second line.

My row arrangement is row > col2 col7 col3 /row. I am not using a v-container because it seems to put a container in the middle and not take up the whole screen.

I have tried using the `flex-wrap`, `flex-column`, `flex-row` etc class based on the vuetify docs, but that doesnt seem to change anything. Most of the examples that I found regarding this is for vuetify 1, and the component structure is different.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-williamson-7wtlr)

`App.vue`

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar
      color="dark"
      dark dense
    >
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-row no-gutters>
      <v-col fluid cols="2"></v-col>

      <v-col fluid cols="7">
        <HelloWorld v-for="c in 10" :key="c" />
      </v-col>

      <v-col fluid cols="3"></v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld';

export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
  }),
};
</script>
```

`HelloWorld.vue`

```
<template>
  <v-card class="mx-auto" max-width="344" outlined>
    <v-list-item three-line>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <div class="overline mb-4">OVERLINE</div>
        <v-list-item-title class="headline mb-1">Headline 5</v-list-item-title>
        <v-list-item-subtitle>Greyhound divisely hello coldly fonwderfully</v-list-item-subtitle>
      </v-list-item-content>

      <v-list-item-avatar tile size="80" color="grey"></v-list-item-avatar>
    </v-list-item>

    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn text>Button</v-btn>
      <v-btn text>Button</v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld"
};
</script>
```

What I have at the moment is this: The arrows are showing how I would like the successive card to be next to the card and so forth.

[image]

Comment: Main problem is that max row size is 12 cols.

Comment: @Asimple I am not sure I follow. the cols are 2,7,3 so 12, and I dont mind resizing the cards as long as they fit horizontally instead of vertically.

Comment: So 12 cols is ended and new line started. Thats why your cards is one under another.

Comment: Still not sure what you are implying. The cards are inside the col with 7 cols...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore row wrap you can just add `.flex-nowrap` class:

```html
<v-row class="flex-nowrap">
```

Update
I get it. You paste card inside of col. My bet.
You just can do this:

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar
      color="dark"
      dark dense
    >
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-row no-gutters>
      <v-col cols="2"></v-col>
      <v-col cols="7">
        <v-row no-gutters>
            <v-col v-for="c in 10" :key="c" cols="4">
                <HelloWorld/>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="3"></v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Comment: I tried your solution to `<v-col fluid cols="7">
        <v-row>
          <HelloWorld v-for="c in 10" :key="c" />
        </v-row>
      </v-col>` but that makes the appbar get bigger.

Comment: @securisec Have you used `no-gutters`?

Comment: yes, as you can see in the code, I used no-gutters. With the code based on the previous comment, it is making the appbar werid. https://imgur.com/a/xwiy7Vx

Comment: @securisec Idk how it should look)

Comment: Based on the imgur link the comments, it is close. But ruwing the row inside the column, it is expanding the appbar which doesnt make sense.

Comment: using your posted solution, this is what I get https://imgur.com/twUi7Ll

Comment: @securisec Ok, i think it would be better if i add whole template to answer

Comment: @securisec Also removed `fluid` from cols.

Comment: Ok got it. But check out this image. https://imgur.com/S7eVudU . The appbar is set to dense, but it is expanding in your solution. Why is that? The appbar is set to dense, so it shouldnt be that wide.

Comment: It appears that when setting the value `4` in the for loop to cols, it is changing the appbar somehow

Comment: @securisec here is example and app-bar is dense:
https://codepen.io/AsimpleUA/pen/bGVyJPb